# Where to ask about electric car battery technology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which is the best site to ask a question about the batteries used in electric cars including environmental stuff?

Basically a question about the environmental effects of the batteries at all stages of their life cycle.

Comment: What kind of question? [mechanics.se] has a [battery] tag but having never been there I can't guarantee all battery-related questions are on-topic.

Comment: I have a feeling that Chemistry may suit but am highly unsure

Comment: @Jenayah it's basically a question about the environmental effects of the batteries at all stages of their life cycle

Answer (score 8):

If the main concern is the environmental effects of the batteries, I think [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) is your best bet.

It's got a [batteries tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries), and [some questions about electric cars](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/search?q=electric+car+is%3Aq) as well.

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to wait for an answer and support a new site try [Area 51's Electric Vehicles](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121450/electric-vehicles?referrer=3xhh2e-xQEPqfcfoejDgWA2) proposal. If it's a great question you can earn a few points on a site where rep is fairly rare.

If you need an answer quickly then [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle) has a tag for electric vehicles. There is also [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) for technical questions about electric vehicle batteries. For even more technical answers try [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brenewable-energy%5D%20%28batteries%5D) which has tags for renewable-energy and batteries.

Comment: Would the Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair site be the best place the for the practicalities aspect of the technology?

Comment: Probably, but a more technical answer would be forthcoming from our engineering site.