# Which SE site is appropriate for asking questions about environmental pollution?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on environmental science. The question is as follows:

> Cement or concrete requires water for setting. And abandoned/garbage concrete remains as solid rocky material. So, is this phenomenon of cement setting cause a net reduction of water from Earth's pool of water?

I cannot yet find a site for environmental science. Where should I put this question i.e. what is the most appropriate Stack Exchange site for it.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327575/where-to-ask-about-electric-car-battery-technology

Comment: Feel free to merge

Comment: So there is no portal of SE for environmental science?

Comment: I think Earth science may be a good fit since it looks for Earth's total water pool.

Comment: Can't merge and no need to merge, it's all good.

Comment: Physics might also be helpfull, as this question is basicly about the process of the setting of concrete. Or the engineering site/departement could help out. They might have a clue on how much water it takes to make concrete, and how much water needs to evaporate for it to set.

Comment: chemistry may help too on degradation of concreted cement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [Sustainable Living site](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/)

Sustainable Living covers

> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources.

It has a [water](/questions/tagged/water) tag for

> Questions regarding sustainable use of water, or water's impact on sustainability in general. For questions on [waste-water], [greywater], [seawater], [water-footprint] or [virtual-water] please use that tag.

It also has other potentially relevant tags for abandoned/garbage things such as a [pollution](/questions/tagged/pollution) tag.

> any addition of harmful substances or products in the environment (air, water, soil or food). For questions specifically about [air-polution], [greenhouse-gas-emissions] or [toxic-chemicals] please use those tags.

But do check out its [help centre](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to find out more.

Comment: thank you for recommending the site